# android google drive api getDownloadUrl return null

Tags: android, google-drive-api

currently i am integrating Google Drive API into my app. I can get the title and mimetype correctly.

However, getDownloadUrl seem to return null. Not only that, getThumbnailLink also return null. What is the possible cause for this problem?

code

```
    Log.d("check", String.valueOf(file.getTitle()));
    Log.d("check", String.valueOf(file.getMimeType()));
    Log.d("check", String.valueOf(file.getDownloadUrl()));
```

result

```
D/check: explore.jpg
D/check: image/jpeg
D/check: null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i know the answer, it is return null due to incorrect DriveScope.

Previously i use DriveScope.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY which caused the file only return metadata. If extra information such as getDownloadUrl and getThumbnailLink, change the DriveScope to DriveScope.DRIVE_READONLY.

More information about DriveScope is available here
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes